# Can I chain @BindBean params?

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbi

`@BindBean` allows me to use properties of bean as params - `myObj.a`.
Can I use property of property of bean - `myObj.a.b`?

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT title FROM user WHERE id = :myObj.a.b")
abstract boolean hasUnmatchedMovie(@BindBean("myObj") MyObject myObject
```

Comment: I think this is a "try it and see" moment. I don't think it would work, but I haven't delved that deeply into the Bean binder JDBI code.

Comment: Yep, it doesn't work. I thought someone suggest workaround

Answer (score 0):

## Analysis

According to the release notes the corresponding feature is available since Jdbi `3.0.0-rc2`: [jdbi/RELEASE_NOTES.md at v3.30.0 · jdbi/jdbi](https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/blob/v3.30.0/RELEASE_NOTES.md?plain=1#L500-L503):

> ## 3.0.0-rc2
>
> <…>
>
> - Binding of nested attributes e.g. ":user.address.city" with bindBean(), bindMethods(),
>   bindFields(), as well as @BindBean, @BindMethods, and @BindFields in SQL objects.

### Additional references

- The [`org.jdbi.v3.core.argument.TestNamedParams.testBeanPropertyNestedBinding()`](https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/blob/v3.0.0-rc2/core/src/test/java/org/jdbi/v3/core/argument/TestNamedParams.java#L105-L106) test method.

## Solution

Upgrade Jdbi version to `3.0.0-rc2` or higher.